# A word that means an event runs for a consecutive period

Tags: single-word-requests

I got a calendaring app and a terminology question.

An event that occurs just once, is a ***one-off***

If it occurs every second Monday, and/or 4th Friday of month it is ***regular***

If it happens on a random series of odd days, it is ***irregular***

But if it starts on 12-jan and runs every weekday until 3-mar and never happens again (like a museum exhibiton), it is ***what-non-technical-one-word***?

Comment: So it doesn't run on weekends. Just the five weekdays for 24 hours a day from 12 jan to 3 march?

Comment: It is also a one-off, just a time taking one.

Comment: I agree, it's a one-off event which spans multiple days.

Comment: In this context, events are almost by definition limited in duration. Within that period, it would be a *daily* event run on weekdays.

Comment: It's continual, if we stretch the meaning to fit it in here. An event running continually only on weekdays from 12 jan to 3 mar.

Comment: What is the most important quality you are trying to convey- its one-timeness or the fact it is longer than one day? Clearly it is still a one-off or one-time event, so what is it about that event that makes you think that one-off is not the best fit? Perhaps it is one-off and the single day one-offs should be called one-day events?

Comment: An answer to the question in the title would be 'multi-day event' but I suspect that is not the kind of thing you wanted to see. It could be a 'one-off multi-day event' which is accurate but not a single word answer.

Comment: @Marv - that it has a duration, a start and end, is for me the important aspect. The sort of event that would be marked on a wall planner with a wiggly line from start to end rather than a series of separated dots.

Comment: @MarvMills is definitely on to something here.  There are really at least two or three orthogonal characteristics that you are trying to sum up in a single word: whether the event happens just once or whether that (type of) event recurs; if the event recurs, whether there is a pattern to its recurrence; and the coverage of a single event that should be represented as extending over multiple days.  You would probably be better off treating at least the last one as the distinct characteristic it is.

Comment: @pellmel - my local record shop has discount fridays. That's regular. They have band appearances. That's one-off (a calendar would show "today only at 14:00" to see the band). They have, this year (perhaps other years too, but that is out of range for the calendar), a two-week summer sale: with a start and end date. A word for that is eluding me :)

Comment: The two-week summer sale is: an event, regular, and recurring :) To imply it is an event that spans consecutive days perhaps use 'Extended Event' - Really the problem here is that you are conflating 'one day long' with 'event'... Events can have *any* duration and still be events.

Comment: @Hardy, and when there is an event that runs multiple times per year for two and a half days each time, but at irregular intervals and inconsistent days of the week?  Yes, you can choose a different term for every possible combination of characteristics, but I think you would be better off describing distinct characteristics with separate words.

Comment: How about an "extended engagement".

Answer (score 1):

I would use 'recurring' for this.

[dictionary](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/recurring)

> recur
>
> > verb (used without object), recurred, recurring.
> >
> > > 1.
> > >       to occur again, as an event, experience, etc.
> > >       2.
> > >       to return to the mind:
> > >       The idea kept recurring.
> > >       3.
> > >       to come up again for consideration, as a question.
> > >       4.
> > >       to have recourse.

The event recurs on weekdays from 12 Jan through 3 Mar.

Answer (score 0):

It is difficult to determine one word that conveys the exact mixture of meanings. However *['extended'](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/extended?s=t)* is an adjective that conveys the meaning of 'smeared out in time'.

> adjective
>
> 1 - stretched out: *extended wires.*
>
> 2- continued or prolonged: *extended efforts.*
>
> 3 - spread out: *extended flags.*
>
> 4 - widespread or extensive; having extension or spatial magnitude: 
>   *extended treatment of a subject.*
>
> *www.dictionary.com*

Thus the event would be called an *'Extended Event'*

Answer (score 0):

If an event is set to occur within a specific period of time, that even has been **scheduled** to occur within that time frame.

```
sched·uled
ˈskeˌjo͞old,-əld/
(adjective)
   1. Included in or planned according to a schedule
   2. Arrange or plan (an event) to take place at a particular time.
```

The museum exhibit was scheduled for showing each weekday from 12 Jan through 3 Mar.

Answer (score 0):

I can't think of a one-word example, but "limited-run" seems appropriate for your use, as in "limited-run television series."

Answer (score 0):

A bit late with this answer but here's how Google calendar describes it:

***Repeats*** every week on weekdays from ___ to ______.

I expect they have carefully considered such scenarios, so I wouldn't reinvent the wheel unnecessarily.

[image: google]