# Expressing hourly temporal recurrence

Tags: time, recurring-events

What is the most idiomatic way to put into words a situation where a recurring event happens every hour at a certain minute. For example, consider that some event takes place at the tenth minute of each hour: *0:10AM, 1:10AM, 2:10AM, ...*

My first ideas were "every hour at the tenth minute" or "every hour at minute 10". Are these options idiomatic and if not, what would be an idiomatic way of expressing this matter?

Comment: *every hour* (or *hourly*) *at 10 after*,  or *ten minutes after every hour*

Answer (score 2):

There are three special cases:

1. “Every hour [on the hour]” — 12:00, 1:00, etc.
2. “Every hour on the half-hour” — 12:30, 1:30, etc.
3. “Every hour on the quarter-hour” — 12:15, 1:15, etc.

Any other offset, as @verbose succinctly pointed out, is “Every hour at *x* [minutes] past the hour.”

(Sometimes "at" is substituted for "on", as is "after" for "past".  Anything is square brackets is optional.)

> “Nietzsche, with his theory of eternal recurrence. He said that the life we lived we’re gonna live over again the exact same way for eternity. Great. That means I’ll have to sit through the Ice Capades again.”
>   ― Woody Allen

Comment: I've heard "on the half/quarter hour" rather than "at".

Comment: @verbose -- yikes, yes, "on" is much more common.  The M-W quote threw me off.

Answer (score 1):

The standard form is *Every hour at x [minutes] past the hour*.  [Merriam-Webster's example](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/past%20the%20hour) is this:

> Trains leave every hour at ten minutes past the hour.

The *minutes* is optional, and my personal preference is to leave it out.

Since [AmE tends to use *after* rather than *past*](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/127307/how-do-they-express-the-time-in-american-and-british-english) to express time, the following might be preferable depending on your audience:

> Trains leave every hour at ten after the hour.

In conversation, one could be quite succinct: *Every hour at ten past/after*, leaving out the subsequent "the hour", would be transparent to most native speakers.

Comment: Is past/after a pondian distinction?  Although, in my head I can hear the BBC voice saying, "It's ten minutes past the hour of six o'clock, and time for _Some Stilted Comedy_..."

Comment: @Malvolio Was that a joke? If so let me know when the next one is coming and I'll be prepared to laugh.

Comment: @WS2 -- well, "pondian" is a back-formation from a mock-formalization ("transpondian") of a meiosis ("across the Pond"), so it's kind of a joke; plus there was a gentle jab at British broadcasting.

Answer (score 0):

*It occurs at 12.10 p.m.and repeats hourly.*

Your could add *forever*, *five times* or *until 4.10 pm*, etc..

Reusing [wording](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/323742/a-word-that-means-an-event-runs-for-a-consecutive-period/363534#363534) from a slightly related question.