# time expression for hour ending in 00?

Tags: expressions, time

I have the following case: "This will be triggered from hour to hour". So if it is 9:32 the trigger will activate on 10:32. My question is: If I want to say from hour to hour BUT I want to say every hour ending in 00. So if it is 9:32 the trigger will be at 10:00.

Is there some kind of expression for that?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Expressing hourly temporal recurrence](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/368454/expressing-hourly-temporal-recurrence) // '... every hour on the hour'.

Comment: It does. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Things that occur at X:00 can be said to occur ***on the hour*** or ***at the top of the hour*** (at X:00, the minute hand is at the top of the clock). If it recurs, you could say it happens ***every hour, on the hour***.